# Send a 64bit Infrared signal with android

Tags: android, infrared, lirc

Using a raspberry pi 3 and an infrared reciver. with the help of a library called LIRC I recorded the signal of my android box remote control.

```
begin remote

    name  MyRemote
    driver devinput
    bits           64
    eps            30
    aeps          100

    one             0     0
    zero            0     0
    pre_data_bits   64
    pre_data       0x0
    gap          509
    toggle_bit_mask 0x0
    frequency    38000

    begin codes
        KEY_1                    0x116B000001000268
        KEY_2                    0x1169000001000267
        KEY_3                    0x116800000100026E
        KEY_4                    0x116E00000100025C
        KEY_5                    0x116C000001000263
        KEY_6                    0x116800000100024E
        KEY_7                    0x115D000001000268
        KEY_8                    0x116E000001000263
        KEY_9                    0x116B000001000267
        KEY_0                    0x116F000001000265
        KEY_DOWN                 0x0360000001000076
        KEY_LEFT                 0x1167000001000264
        KEY_UP                   0x117800000100025E
        KEY_RIGHT                0x1169000001000266
        KEY_BACK                 0x1170000001000262
        KEY_ENTER                0x1167000001000268
    end codes

end remote
```

The problem is I can not find a library that can help me write code to send the IR signal from my Note3.

Comment: Check this https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1670289

Comment: And this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/ConsumerIrManager

Answer (score 4):

I tested [ConsumerIrManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/ConsumerIrManager) on Redmi Note 4, probably it will work on Note3 too.

Add permission to the manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR" />`

And in code:

1. Retrieve `ConsumerIrManager`

```
val irService = getSystemService(Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE) as ConsumerIrManager
```

2. Check if emitter exists

```
irService.hasIrEmitter()
```

3. Check if target frequency is supported by emitter

```
fun isSupportedFrequency(irService: ConsumerIrManager, targetFreq: Int): Boolean {
        irService.carrierFrequencies.forEach {
            if (it.minFrequency <= targetFreq && targetFreq <= it.maxFrequency) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
}
```

4. Transmit data

```
irService.transmit(targetFreq, data)
```

### UPD1:

To send 64 bit keys maybe you can split them into two 32 bit keys.

### UPD2:

Under the hood `ConsumerIrManager` uses [`ConsumerIrService`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConsumerIrService.java), which uses native method `private static native int halTransmit(int carrierFrequency, int[] pattern);`, which supports only 32 bit pattern slices. So probably there is no hacky way to send 64 bit slices, if splitting won't help.

Answer (score 2):

It's not good solution, but anyway, you can convert your 64bit IR codes into wav signals (or even record it directly from IR remote) and send it via [`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) (or other player) to your android box by external IR transmitter on audio out like [this](https://electronics2017.wordpress.com/) or [that](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-an-IR-Blaster/).